# where to find Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I am in the process to setup our new Win7 build machine for our C# project. We don't want to install Visual Studio on that machine. So I am following the instruction "[Running mstest without Visual Studio](http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/04/23/running-mstest-without-visual-studio/)" to setup our machine.

On step 3:

```
    Put Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll and
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll in the GAC on the CIServer,
 because that is where they are on the DevMachine.
```

On my develoopment machine (installed Visual Studio 2008 professional version) I found both of them in my GAC (C:\windows\assembly) but I searched my entire development machine and couldn't find the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll`

My questions are:

1. where to get the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll`?
2. can I copy above file from GAC? (I tried `gacutil.exe`, there is no such copy option. I tried `Control Panel->Administrative Tools`, but my XP machine only has `Microsoft .Net Framework 1.1 Configuration` on which above two assembly didn't show up.)?

thanks,

Comment: Erm, you found them in the GAC on your dev machine.  But you searched the entire dev machine and couldn't find them.  Does not compute.

Comment: Could be I have installed previous version of Visual Studio and unintalled them before. Could be I delete it by accident?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525487/vs2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-unitt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy files from the GAC via cmd.exe. E.g.:

```
copy C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll C:\Temp
```

Adjust the version appropriately.

Windows Explorer just replaces the subfolders in C:\Windows\assembly with the aggregated view you might know.

Comment: I cannot see GAC_MSIL under assembly folder, only one subfolder there which is named "download".

Answer (score 2):

my Version Of this Dll currently sites at the following location C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0 due to using vs2010 so change the path accordingly to get it from your machine

if you need to run this in isolation create a tools folder in your folder structure thats checked into source control and then reference the dll from that tools folder and NOT from the GAC. this means that when it builds on the build machine it wont need Visual Studio installed

Comment: I searched few times and cannot find it inside the Program Files folder.

Comment: so you have visual studio 2008 therefore the path should be this C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies - its there on my machine - copy this to a tools folder and then remove the project reference and then reference from the tools folder

Comment: no need to reinstall - go to your visual studio solution where the dll is referenced and look at the properties of the dll and see the path - go there and find it and copy it to the tools folder

Comment: just reinstall VS 2008 professional, still cannnot find that dll and I looked at my solution reference nowhere to find that dll. maybe we don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a 64 bit machine. In that case, it's here.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below if you use **VS2008**

```
copy C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll c:\temp
```